# How to make static library modular in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, static-libraries, swift4

As after release of Swift 4, Swift is supporting Static library. But when I am trying to make use of Static binary inside application, it showing error with undefined module.

We are creating SDK with modular structure with 15 framework one for each module, but as Apple suggest it is not good to add more than 6 dynamic framework(As dynamic linking slow down app launch time.). 
So after support of static lib in Swift, we decided to convert it to static library and then create one dynamic framework which provide facade interface for all 15 frameworks.

I created one Static lib named `StaticA` an try to add it in Dynamic Framework, but it shows below error.

`No such module 'StaticA'`

[image]

I also set `Defines Modules` to `Yes` but it does not helping.
Is it possible to make Static library modular using Swift ?
If Yes, then suggest way.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: have you gotten anywhere with this?

Comment: Still not found way to do that.

Answer (score 7):

There's a few build settings you need to enable:

```
MODULEMAP_FILE = $(PRODUCT_NAME)/module.modulemap
SWIFT_INCLUDE_PATHS = $(PRODUCT_NAME)
DEFINES_MODULE = YES
```

The other option which works (without modifying the build settings) is to copy the `modulemap` file to the products directory under `include/$(PRODUCT_NAME)`

Note:

- I generally put the `modulemap` in the top level of the module directory
- i.e. one level down from the `xcodeproj` file:

  - `StaticA.xcodeproj` then I would have at `StaticA/module.modulemap`

What this allow's you to do is define a `module.modulemap` for your library:

```
module StaticA {
    header "StaticA-Swift.h"
}
```

Typically `StaticA-Swift.h` isn't available and won't be generated, you "might" be able to get away with not specifying it ... but I've not had any luck and have needed to do it manually.

You can use a script which will copy the generated `*-Swift.h` to the include folder so that you are able to reference it from your `modulemap` file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

target_dir=${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/include/${PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME}/

# Ensure the target include path exists
mkdir -p "${target_dir}"

# Copy any file that looks like a Swift generated header to the include path
cp "${DERIVED_SOURCES_DIR}/"*-Swift.h "${target_dir}"
```

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Project's Build Phases

and

Click on the "+" under "Link Binary With Libraries" to add a new library. Then click on the "Add Other" button.

and pls also ensure you have the lib path to `Library Search Paths` under *Build Settings*

Comment: then pls check path at  _FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS_  also.

Comment: No need to set framework search path, we are dealing with library.
I need to make library modular.